# Connect trough remote computer connection

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008

First, sorry for my english and my poor knowlodge of this subject.

I have a dedicated server placed in Germany (windows 2008 R2) and I live in spain. I would like to access internet from my home computer (Windows 7 Pro x64), trough my server in Germany, so I can use a German IP, what I need some times.

I have complete acces in to both computers, but I just don't know where to start. (My knwoledge is limited to software development :/ )

I'd like to know where to start, if I need to create a VPN and so..

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

I tried a lot of options of OpenVPN, but I sadly I know nothing abuot networking, so I have to accept I do not know what I'm doing :(

Here are my config files (note most of the options are from the sample config files).

server.conf

```
#server config file start


port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.224   #you may choose any subnet. 10.0.0.x is used for this example.

ca "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt" 
cert "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.crt" 
key "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.key" 
dh "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh1024.pem" 

push "redirect-gateway def1"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

#the following commands are optional
keepalive 10 120         
comp-lzo                   
persist-key               
persist-tun               
verb 5                   


#config file ends
```

client.conf

```
#client  config file start

client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 176.9.99.180 1194   

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\client1.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\client1.key"
ns-cert-type server

comp-lzo
verb 5
explicit-exit-notify 2
ping 10
ping-restart 60

route-method exe
route-delay 2

# end of client config file
```

And here's the server's network settings:

IP address: 176.9.99.180
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.224
Default gateway: 176.9.99.161

Preferred DNS server: 127.0.0.1

**Update 2**

Here's the routing table:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...00 ff e4 70 31 16 ......TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
 11...54 04 a6 7e ee ae ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 10...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     176.9.99.161     176.9.99.180     11
         10.0.0.0  255.255.255.224         10.0.0.2         10.0.0.1     30
         10.0.0.0  255.255.255.252         On-link          10.0.0.1    286
         10.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    286
         10.0.0.3  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     176.9.99.160  255.255.255.224         On-link      176.9.99.180    266
     176.9.99.180  255.255.255.255         On-link      176.9.99.180    266
     176.9.99.191  255.255.255.255         On-link      176.9.99.180    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      176.9.99.180    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      176.9.99.180    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     176.9.99.161       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 10     58 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 10     58 2001::/32                On-link
 10    306 2001:0:5ef5:73b8:ce2:1218:4ff6:9c4b/128
                                    On-link
 14    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    306 fe80::ce2:1218:4ff6:9c4b/128
                                    On-link
 14    286 fe80::7c23:a:ec4e:2cfc/128
                                    On-link
 11    266 fe80::bd18:6249:9f7d:89a2/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Try this? http://superuser.com/questions/390056/setting-up-a-computer-for-remote-access

Comment: Actually I see that post is only por RDP, which I already have, what I need is something like this web (amd similar ones) offer: http://www.purevpn.com/order/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to use a German IP, you can install/configure a proxy on the server and access internet using this proxy on your home computer.

A VPN would do the job too but I think it's too much if you only need to access internet with a German IP.

Comment: Just to be clear, don't need JUST to access web with a german IP, but all of my traffic. I'm using programs that have been recently forbidden in my country and need to use another country's IP.

Comment: If you install the proxy, be sure to restrict its access so only you (or people you select) can use it and do not let it open to everybody.

Comment: with the proxy, all your internet traffic can be routed via the german IP, no problem but if the traffic is forbidden, maybe better to istall a VPN server and encrypt the connection so nobody will be able to see what is going through the tunnel, you cna have a look at http://openvpn.net

Comment: Ok thanks! I will install a proxy, test, and come back with the results!

Comment: After lots of tests, I decided to use VPN. I used this tutorial on how to set it up in windows 7 https://forums.openvpn.net/topic7806.html, adapting a few things for Windows Server 2008 r2.

I have client and server AND connected, but no trafic is redirected through vpn.

Comment: There's a point in the mentioned tutorial that tells to activate "Network sharing". I'm not sure that's needed in server 2008, but anyway it won'r allow me.

Comment: I think you need to use `redirect-gateway` directive and set a route with `route-up 'route change 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1'`. I'm not using it on windows but I think you'll need to define the route in a batch script and call it from the config file: https://forums.openvpn.net/topic7082.html

Comment: Edited to add new information.

Comment: The only I know at this moment is that the VPN is working (I can see shared files). The conection in the server has no internet access.

Comment: I've found somewhere in the internet I have to bridge networks adapters, but I have no idea how :S 
I have tried going to network connections, selecting both adapters, and right click->bridge, but I lose internet connectivity.

Comment: Edited to add the routing table